# proctected variable inside a protected class

Tags: java, scjp

Im trying to declare a protected variable inside a protected class but get an error,

```
protected class Car {
    protected int x = 9;
}
```

The valid modifier for the class is public, abstract and final as per Eclipse.

Can someone please explain?

Comment: If `Car` is a top-level class, it doesn't make any sense to make it `protected`.  `Protected` members of a class are things that are visible to that class and to subclasses.  But a top-level class isn't a member of any other class.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you explain what you think a "protected class" is, and why you want `Car` to be that.  Then we might be able to figure out what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

A class (or interface) cannot be protected, only fields and methods within a class can be.  However, there is an exception where if you have nested (or inner) classes or interfaces you can in fact label them as protected.  I am assuming that your class is a top level class though, hence why you are receiving an error message.

Comment: Clarification: A class declared within another class (nested or inner class) **can** be protected.  So can a nested interface.  The tutorial is not quite accurate here.

Comment: True, I probably shouldn't have assumed it wasn't a nested class (or interface)  I was just looking for a reference for OP and saw that since Oracle's tutorials doesn't really explain what you can't do in that aspect.  I'll update the answer